# How to implement a Q-hofstadter sequence through a generator?

Tags: python, loops, recursion, math, generator

I tried through recursion and a loop, but I want to use generators, but I didn’t understand how to implement it.

```
def Q(n):
    if n < 3:
        return 1
    return Q(n-Q(n-1)) + Q(n-Q(n-2))
 
n = 33
print(Q(n))
```

I can't figure out how to get rid of recursion through generators (yield instead of return)? How to transform such an expression (**Q(n-Q(n-1)) + Q(n-Q(n-2))**) so that it can be calculated through yield?

Comment: You're not really generating anything, so why do you want a generator? It might be different if, for example, you wanted to **generate** the sequence Q(1), Q(2), Q(3), ..., Q(n-1), Q(n). But you just want to compute Q(n). NOTE: You could create a generator for Q(1), Q(2),..., Q(n) and then just take the last element of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

```
num = int(input())
dict = {1:1, 2:1, 3:2}
keys = list(dict.keys())
def q(n):
    if n in keys:
        x = dict[n]
    else:
        x = q(n-q(n-1)) + q(n-q(n-2))
    return x
    
print(q(num))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution.